# Uploading file via ssh, how to block it until the transfer done?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I'll explain it:

I got apache installed on my Linux Ubuntu and i need to upload some big files and I want to make it available to download only when the transfer done.

it's possible to do it?

Comment: stop the apache? User's download is your upload so just stop the apache then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upload it under a user's account that Apache can't access and then `chown` OR upload it to a temp dir and `mv` it into place?

Comment: yes it will work, thanks. but maybe i could do it with some httpd.conf or on ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a PHP script (or similar device) that only permits a file to be seen or downloaded if it hasn't been modified for at least a minute.